# How to convert between equivalent enum types?

Tags: rust

I have an `avro_rs::types::Value::Double(f64)` and need an `influx_db_client::Value::Float(f64)`. I'm converting between the two using the following code:

```rust
let pr = recmap.get(&"price".to_string()).unwrap();
match pr {
    Double(p) => {
        let price = influx_db_client::Value::Float(*p);
        point.add_field("price", price);
    },
    _ => ()
}
```

Is there a shorter or more idiomatic way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Why `&"price".to_string()` and not just `"price"` ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`if let` pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html) helps you replace the whole with

```
if let Some(Double(p)) = recmap.get("price") {
    let price = influx_db_client::Value::Float(*p);
    point.add_field("price", price);
}
```

Most usually you would also have a few `use` statement to avoid having `influx_db_client::Value::Float` in the middle of the code.

Side note: a difference here is that if `recmap.get` returns `None`, your code crashes with `unwrap()` while mine ignores it.